# Tensornets ERROR instalation ubuntu anaconda environment

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, anaconda, python-3.6, miniconda

I tried to install tensornets in my ubuntu anaconda environment but the message bellow appears.
I installed:

- numpy 1.17.0,
- tensoflow 1.14.0,
- pandas 1.1.5,
- opencv,
- keras,
- cmake,
- dlib

  ```
   $ pip install tensornets
  ```

collecting tensornets
Using cached tensornets-0.4.6.tar.gz (651 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
WARNING: Missing build requirements in pyproject.toml for tensornets from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/22/2c9402bbf142b94dc39d8a3c9884690ae87706a8bc1453d6cf0630525173/tensornets-0.4.6.tar.gz#sha256=e1095082b45a06168d56450d8c8fa49780d8aef8d4d1fcc64efceadb743f9ceb.
WARNING: The project does not specify a build backend, and pip cannot fall back to setuptools without 'wheel'.
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: tensornets
Building wheel for tensornets (PEP 517) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /home/mario/miniconda3/envs/VARVO_LINUX/bin/python /home/mario/miniconda3/envs/VARVO_LINUX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmp2bm7gwnh
cwd: /tmp/pip-install-vupow4g5/tensornets_24fc2060cce2460b9b6417949ee1e6b6
Complete output (86 lines):
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/unet.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/inceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/densenets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/preprocess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/capsulenets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/tnets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/resnets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/nasnets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/middles.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/version_utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/squeezenets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/vggs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/darknets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/zf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/layers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/pretrained.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/mobilenets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/ops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/detections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/efficientnets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
copying tensornets/wavenets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/datasets
copying tensornets/datasets/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/datasets
copying tensornets/datasets/imagenet.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/datasets
copying tensornets/datasets/voc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/datasets
copying tensornets/datasets/coco.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/datasets
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/contrib_framework
copying tensornets/contrib_framework/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/contrib_framework
copying tensornets/contrib_framework/arg_scope.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/contrib_framework
copying tensornets/contrib_framework/variables.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/contrib_framework
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/contrib_layers
copying tensornets/contrib_layers/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/contrib_layers
copying tensornets/contrib_layers/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/contrib_layers
copying tensornets/contrib_layers/initializers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/contrib_layers
copying tensornets/contrib_layers/normalization.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/contrib_layers
copying tensornets/contrib_layers/optimizers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/contrib_layers
copying tensornets/contrib_layers/layers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/contrib_layers
copying tensornets/contrib_layers/regularizers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/contrib_layers
copying tensornets/contrib_layers/summaries.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/contrib_layers
copying tensornets/contrib_layers/rev_block_lib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/contrib_layers
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references
copying tensornets/references/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references
copying tensornets/references/rcnns.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references
copying tensornets/references/yolo_utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references
copying tensornets/references/rpn_utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references
copying tensornets/references/yolos.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references/darkflow_utils
copying tensornets/references/darkflow_utils/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references/darkflow_utils
copying tensornets/references/darkflow_utils/box.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references/darkflow_utils
running egg_info
writing tensornets.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to tensornets.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to tensornets.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'tensornets.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'tensornets.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
copying tensornets/datasets/coco.names -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/datasets
copying tensornets/datasets/voc.names -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/datasets
copying tensornets/references/coco.names -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references
copying tensornets/references/voc.names -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references
copying tensornets/references/darkflow_utils/**init**.pyc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references/darkflow_utils
copying tensornets/references/darkflow_utils/box.pyc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references/darkflow_utils
copying tensornets/references/darkflow_utils/get_boxes.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references/darkflow_utils
copying tensornets/references/darkflow_utils/get_boxes.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references/darkflow_utils
copying tensornets/references/darkflow_utils/get_boxes.so -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references/darkflow_utils
copying tensornets/references/darkflow_utils/nms.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references/darkflow_utils
copying tensornets/references/darkflow_utils/nms.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references/darkflow_utils
copying tensornets/references/darkflow_utils/nms.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references/darkflow_utils
copying tensornets/references/darkflow_utils/nms.so -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references/darkflow_utils
running build_ext
building 'tensornets.references.darkflow_utils.nms' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references/darkflow_utils
gcc -pthread -B /home/mario/miniconda3/envs/VARVO_LINUX/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-env-*5o3ttz*/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/mario/miniconda3/envs/VARVO_LINUX/include/python3.6m -c tensornets/references/darkflow_utils/nms.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/tensornets/references/darkflow_utils/nms.o
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for tensornets
Failed to build tensornets
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tensornets which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the gcc compiler
I followed this tutorial: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-ubuntu-18-04/ 
In summary:
1.- Update

$sudo apt update

2.- Install build-essential

$sudo apt install build-essential

2.1.- Optional (documentation)

$sudo apt-get install manpages-dev

3.- Verify GCC compiler installation

$gcc --version